# how disable remoteReporter in quarkus-smallrye-opentracing

Tags: java, quarkus, jaeger, opentracing, smallrye

**Request description:**.
I want disable jaeger client remoteReporter, I don't nee send to agent, Because istio would make it.

**Tried:**.
Add `quarkus.jaeger.sender-factory` prop in my application.properties
but I not has lucky, and can't find when use this prop in source code.

**env infomation:**

java version: 1.8.
quarkus version: 1.13.2.Final

**example project**.
[GitLab link](https://gitlab.com/luciferstut/opentracing-quickstart)

Comment: So you essentially want to not have the application perform any tracing?

Comment: No, I need tracing and propagation tracing headers, I only want disable reporter. my application deploy on the k8s environment, In my situation, application unknown agent host. istio will duties of report.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `io.jaegertracing.internal.senders.SenderResolver` which determines the Sender to use is pretty broken, which is why `quarkus.jaeger.sender-factory` isn't being taken into account.

One way to achieve what you want is to add a service loader file, i.e. add a file named `resources/META-INF/services/io.jaegertracing.spi.SenderFactory` that contains this single line:

`io.jaegertracing.internal.senders.NoopSenderFactory`

Comment: I tried that solution and use debug mode check that.  But it not working for me.
I create an example project can reproduce the problem when the question context. Could you help me look it?

Comment: I found some bad news, T__T  https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/quarkusio/quarkus/15799/803531912

Comment: Sure. I tried it and it worked for me, so you have a reproducer, just mention in the original question and I'll take a look

Answer (score 0):

Try to exlude jaeger-thrift in the pom, like this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-opentracing</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>io.jaegertracing</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaeger-thrift</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

what i can see in the log is only one warning about "No sender factories available. Using NoopSender".

If you add the file in meta-inf/services like the previous answer, you will not get any warnings like i describe.